# How to load resolve multiple loaders of a node module?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I have made multiple loaders available in an npm module. I want different projects to load these webpack loaders based on needs. So I bundled them into one module. How can I add these loaders in the webpack config?

Following are ways I tried for module named `test-module` and loader `test-loader`

1. expecting it directly resolves the module(`test-loader` is even set through exports) and uses the loader.

```
loader: 'test-module/test-loader'
```

2. Tried adding config in `resolveLoader`

```
resolveLoader: {
    modules: ['node_modules', 'test-module'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.json'],
    mainFields: ['loader', 'main'],
  }
```

and

```
loader: 'test-loader'
```

3. Even tried giving the relative path of the folder.

```
resolveLoader: {
    modules: ['node_modules', 'node_modules\test-module\loaders'],
    extensions: ['.js', '.json'],
    mainFields: ['loader', 'main'],
  }
```

and

```
loader: 'test-loader'
```

All the above didn't work. But directly giving relative path in the loader worked.

```
loader: './node_modules/test-module/'
```

Is there any better way than giving relative paths?